# Resize images while using databinding

Tags: imageresizer

Is there a way to use [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net/) while using databinding?

```
<img class="link-scale" alt="picture" src='<%# Eval("Name", "{0}?w=160&h=90") %>' style="padding:0 5px 10px 0;" />
```

"Name" contains the image's name (e.g. house.png).

I tried it like mentioned above but it's not working.

Any advice? Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImageResizer can certainly work with databinding - or any other kind of HTML generation. It only cares about the URL it receives from the web browser; it is not aware of the page containing that URL.

If an image is not working, you should open the Network tab of your browser, and look for failed requests. When you see the corresponding request, copy and paste the URL that is generated back into your question here, and we can help you determine what is wrong with it.

Comment: This is the URL I get. But there are no failed requests..
I've got this URL by following the instructions on the website (In IE, right-click the image and choose Properties. Copy and paste the Address (URL) field contents into the address bar of a new window.)

file://server-name/folder/subfolder/MM%20sunset-grey-bw.jpg?w=100&h=75&mode=crop

Comment: Your URL should start with "http://" or "https://", and the server-name must be the server where ImageResizer is installed. Local file URLs will not work on the web.

Comment: Gotcha! :) Thank you very much Computer Linguist!